# Good practice to get an object from Firebase?

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I have an object called `users` storing profile information (`name` and `email`) of the user per `uid`.

I am trying to figure out the way to retrieve this profile information when the user is logged in and display it in the DOM. What is a good practice to do so?

Here is what I tried so far. While `currentAuth` is resolved correctly (and thus `authData.uid`), it does not load the profile information in `$scope.User`.

**States**

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

  .state("home", {
      url: "/home",
      templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
      controller: "AppCtrl",
      resolve: {
        // controller will not be loaded until $waitForAuth resolves
        // Auth refers to our $firebaseAuth wrapper in the example above
        "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth) {
          // $waitForAuth returns a promise so the resolve waits for it to complete
          return Auth.$waitForAuth();
        }]
      }
    })
  .state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
    controller: 'AppCtrl',
    resolve: {
        // controller will not be loaded until $requireAuth resolves
        // Auth refers to our $firebaseAuth wrapper in the example above
        "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth) {
          // $requireAuth returns a promise so the resolve waits for it to complete
          // If the promise is rejected, it will throw a $stateChangeError (see above)
          return Auth.$requireAuth();
        }]
    }
  })
  .state('app.account', {
    url: "/account",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/account.html",
        controller: 'AccountCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

// other states

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/playlists');
});
```

**Account Ctrl**

```
.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope, Users, currentAuth) {

      if(currentAuth) {
        $scope.User = Users.getUser(currentAuth.uid);
        $scope.authData = currentAuth;
      }
})
```

**User Service**

```
.factory('Users', function() {
  var ref = new Firebase("https://<yourapp>.firebaseio.com/");
  return {
    getUser: function(userId){
        var refChild = ref.child("users").child(userId);
        var fnReturn = function(snap) {
          console.log(snap.val()) // works perfect!
          return snap.val();
        }
        return refChild.on('value', fnReturn)
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Per docs @ https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/on.html, your Users.getUser() function is returning a reference to fnReturn. So $scope.Users is just a function reference, not the dataset. Since you seem to be using the AngularFire library for authentication, I'd recommend you use the AngularFire $firebase object to get your data, and take advantage of the promises it gives you for properly loading data into your scope.

Comment: That looks like an answer Mike!